# C# double subtraction

Tags: c#, double, subtraction

I need to do some work with variables of the type double and in the calculations I've come across something I do not understand. I know floating point types are not exact but it has enough precision for what I need.

First I multiply a value of **200** with a multiplier of **1.1** and get **220.00000000000003** which is expected and close enough to **220** and then I subtract that from the expected value (**220**). The result should be **0** or very close to **0**. Instead I get **-2.8421709430404007E-14** which I cannot explain.

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double u = 200;
            double v = 1.1;
            double x = u * v;
            double y = 220;
            double z = y - x;

            Console.WriteLine(u + " * " + v + " = " + x);

            Console.WriteLine(y + " - " + x + " = " + z);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `-2.8421709430404007E-14` is close to zero (i.e. move the decimal place 14 times to the *left*).

Comment: -2.8421709430404007E-14 means `-2.84 * 10 ^ -14`. really close. more information about [Scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)

Comment: Please learn scientific notation.

Comment: In other words, the result is very close to (but not quite) `-0.00000000000003`

Comment: That's very close to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a number very close to 0.  It's scientific notation; the E-14 means 10^-14.  In other words, shift the decimal point 14 places to the left.

There are libraries that make working with floating-point operations a little more intuitive; otherwise, you'll need to figure out and test against a tolerance in order to see whether you're "close enough."

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using the "decimal" type - your code looks like C#.net.
This has high precision and is designed to work as you would expect (for financial calculation etc.).

Give it a try! :-)